# Hide previous months, dates and years in datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I am using datepicker in my project for expiration date column. I want to hide previous months, dates and years in datepicker. I dont know how to do it.

```
$('#auto_id').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: start,
    maxDate: end,
    yearRange: start.getFullYear() + ':' + end.getFullYear()
});
```

can anybody help me?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you allowing past days, eg `01 Feb 2015` would be valid (as its in the current month), but `01 Jan 2015` would not?

Comment: Only I want to display from current date. This is for expiration date so I dont need previous dates.

Comment: Set `minDate: 0`. I don't know what your `start` variable contains though.